# Unable to get Second Large value in array

Tags: java, arrays, search

I dont understand what is wrong with this code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Float[] arr = new Float[6];
    arr[0] = 8.25F;
    arr[1] = 8.25F;
    arr[2] = 8.25F;
    arr[3] = 0.0F;
    arr[4] = 0.0F;
    arr[5] = 0.0F;

    secondHighest(arr);

}

public static float secondHighest(Float[] arr) {
    float largest = arr[0];
    float secondLargest = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = arr[i];

        } else if (arr[i] > secondLargest) {
            secondLargest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(secondLargest);
    return secondLargest;
}
```

It is printing 8.25 which is the largest value. instead of 0.0

**UPDATE:** 
I do not want to use any of the collection classes. Because I do not want to change the order of the array elements. **If all the inputs are same my method should return 0.0** (which is default value for float) as output.

Comment: What second largest do you expect in values `[8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 6.0, 0.0]`? I guess 6.0, right?

Comment: @MaheshVarma What should be the output if all input are same??

Comment: If all inputs are same I need to get 0.0 as the second largest number. @AchintyaJha

Comment: By that logic, three of those elements would have to be the largest. Can you have more than one largest? By definition I don't think so. Tell your teacher it was a trick question.

Comment: I think u did not understand the question.I need to get the second biggest number from a list @Leifingson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When if the value is not larger than the previous largest then you are not checking to see whether it was equal to the previous largest before setting the second largest:

```
    public static float secondHighest(Float[] arr) {
        float largest = arr[0];
        float secondLargest = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        boolean foundSecondLargest = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > largest) {
                secondLargest = largest;
                largest = arr[i];
                foundSecondLargest = true;
            } else if ( arr[i] != largest && arr[i] > secondLargest) {
                secondLargest = arr[i];
                foundSecondLargest = true;
            }
        }
        if ( !foundSecondLargest )
            secondLargest = 0.0F;
        System.out.println( String.format("%.2f", secondLargest ) );
        return secondLargest;
    }
```

**Edit**

Added a check to see if no second largest value was found and, if so, return `0.0F`.

Comment: This is exactly the problem.

Comment: It is printing 8.2. It is not considering the last decimal @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo

Comment: If I have 8.25F and 8.20F It is just printing 8.2 @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo

Comment: `System.out.println( String.format("%.2f", secondLargest ) );`

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just do this:

```
Float[] arr = new Float[6];
arr[0] = 8.25F;
arr[1] = 8.25F;
arr[2] = 8.25F;
arr[3] = 0.0F;
arr[4] = 0.0F;
arr[5] = 0.0F;
List<Float> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
Collections.sort(list);
Float secondLargest = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
if (list.size() > 1) { 
    secondLargest = list.get(1)
}
```

If you don't want to use any of the collection utility classes, you can (bubble) sort your array and return the second element.

Comment: My requirement is not to use Any of the collection classes.

Comment: @MaheshVarma than first answer is best..to your need... just one line and without collections ;) :)

Comment: OP doesn't want the value at the second position. See question comments.

Comment: `Float[] arr = new Float[]{ 0.0F };` will throw an error. The OP's original function would expect to return `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` (or by recent comments would expect `0.0` to be returned)

Answer (score 3):

Many answers here suggest ordering the data set and get the second element. That is a cool solution since you can solve your problem in few lines but. What happens if you have a huge dataset? In that case those solutions are unnecessarily increasing the your code time complexity.

Your problem is that you have repeated values so your second largest value is 8.25 too.

You should change your "else-if" condition so the second largest could not be equal to the largest value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 Arrays.sort(arr);
 System.out.println(arr[1]);
```

Comment: Just in one Line :) Good One +1

Comment: Will still return `8.25` which is not what the OP was after.

Comment: OP doesn't want the value at the second position. See question comments.

Comment: @MT0 if all inputs are same then what OP expects output?

Comment: Expected output is `0.0` for the input in the original question. Based on the function in the OP then if all the array element are the same then it should return `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`.